# Multiple units of a singular shelf... If I refer to the group of units, should I use "shelfs" or "shelves"

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

I have multiple packages with a single shelf inside.

If I refer to the multiple packages using some form or variation of "shelf" instead of "packages", should I use "shelfs" or "shelves?"

My inclination is to use "shelfs", since I'm referring to multiple singular units, rather than the all the shelves together as a group entity. Or am I completely off-base here?

Is there a specific name for this non-standard convention, if it exists? (Bonus brownie points if someone can answer if this convention exists in non-English languages.)

Comment: *Shelves* is the singular of *shelve*, which is plural: *he shelves, they shelve*. This is no irregular. It works just like *she halves* in the singular but *they halve* in the plural, or when cows or glaciers are involved, then *she calves* singular and *they calve* plural. And *he leaves* and *he delves*  but *they leave* and *they delve*.  I guess you can say *he leafs* and *she calfs* and *he halfs* and *he delfs* and *he shelfs* if you really want to, but I reckon folks will think you half a bat speech impetiment of some kint.  :)

Comment: @tchrist - I think we can shelve any discussion of the verb form, that's not what the OP asked about.

Comment: If you feel that the usual plural "shelves" doesn't address some problem with what you want to talk about, then please could you clarify what you mean by "units" and "packages", and how thet relate to the shelves? I don't see how multiple packages can have just one shelf inside. Perhaps you could just refer to the units or packages? Or, if the shelves must be mentioned, "shelf units"? Some pieces of furniture that contain shelves are called shelf units.

Comment: @RosieF idk, it just feels weird to talk about multiple (box containing a single shelf) as "shelves" when "shelves" implies that the entire group should be considered a single unit, when it is in fact multiple/separate units, which are not designed to fit or go together.

Comment: I suppose this is in the same vein as "mouse", "mice" and "mouses"?

Comment: Each horizontal platform is a shelf. Multiple of them are shelves. If multiple shelves are organized into single unit that is a shelving unit. You could refer to them collectively as shelves and that’s ok cuz they are.  You would not talk about the second shelves down if you meant the second shelving unit in the hallway.

Comment: Okay, I'll accept that "shelfs" doesn't exist. (Even though constructs like "mice" and "mouses" exist.)

Comment: I'll delete the question

Answer (score 5):

In English, the only plural of "shelf" is "shelves".  I guess that if you use "shelfs" (without some explanation), your readers will just assume that English is not your native language, so you did not know any better.